# Invertibility of trace duals of orders in number fields

Tags: number-theory, ideals, trace, gorenstein

Let $K \subseteq L$ be number fields and $S$ be an order in $L$ (not necessarily maximal). Let $R:=S\cap K$ and $S^*$ such as $R^*$ denote the trace duals of $S$ and $R$, respectively. Then $S^*$ and $R^*$ are fractional ideals of $S$ and $R$, respectively.

I am looking for a sufficient condition on $S$ such that

(1) $R^*$ is invertible in $R$ and

(2) $R^*S$ is invertible in $S$.

Let me note that (1) is an equivalent description of $R$ being Gorenstein, so my first approach was to assume $S$ to be Gorenstein, but i was not able to deduce (1) and (2) from this.

Thank you for every hint!

Comment: (1) implies (2). If $R$ is monogenic then the trace dual is $\frac1{f'(a)} R$ ?